# Print file with column numbers

Tags: awk

My file looks something like this:

```
--------------------------VREV-C-SEQAETGPCRAMISRWYFDVTEGKCAPFFYGGCGGNRNNFDTEEYCMAVCG-----
--P-----------------------RRKL-C-ILHRNPGRCYDKIPAFYYNQKKKQCERFDWSGCGGNSNRFKTIEECRRTCIG----
--------------------------APDF-C-LEPPYDGPCRALHLRYFYNAKAGLCQTFYYGGCLAKRNNFESAEDCMRTC------
```

How can I add a header with the respective column number with a readable format, a.k.a. adding spaces so that a two digit column number doesn't make it unreadable.

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 ....
- - - - - - - - -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  V  R  E  V...
```

I need the user to see this output to select the column number where he wants to cut.

Comment: what you are showing are column number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard way of doing this not modifying the column spacing but creating the multi digit column number vertically.  For example,

```
$ awk 'NR==1{n=length(); 
            if(n>10) for(i=0;i<n;i++) printf "%s", int(i/10); print "";
            for(i=1;i<=n;i++) printf "%s",i%10; print ""}1' file


00000000001111111111222222222233333333334444444444555555555566666666667777777777888888888
12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
--------------------------VREV-C-SEQAETGPCRAMISRWYFDVTEGKCAPFFYGGCGGNRNNFDTEEYCMAVCG-----
--P-----------------------RRKL-C-ILHRNPGRCYDKIPAFYYNQKKKQCERFDWSGCGGNSNRFKTIEECRRTCIG----
--------------------------APDF-C-LEPPYDGPCRALHLRYFYNAKAGLCQTFYYGGCLAKRNNFESAEDCMRTC------
```

this is done up to 99 columns but can be extended easily for higher digits as well.

For readability, perhaps you can group the blocks by 10.

```
... | sed -E 's/(.{10})/\1 /g'

0000000000 1111111111 2222222222 3333333333 4444444444 5555555555 6666666666 7777777777 888888888
1234567890 1234567890 1234567890 1234567890 1234567890 1234567890 1234567890 1234567890 123456789
---------- ---------- ------VREV -C-SEQAETG PCRAMISRWY FDVTEGKCAP FFYGGCGGNR NNFDTEEYCM AVCG-----
--P------- ---------- ------RRKL -C-ILHRNPG RCYDKIPAFY YNQKKKQCER FDWSGCGGNS NRFKTIEECR RTCIG----
---------- ---------- ------APDF -C-LEPPYDG PCRALHLRYF YNAKAGLCQT FYYGGCLAKR NNFESAEDCM RTC------
```

The format you described can be done as well, not sure will be more useful though

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {FS=""; OFS="  "} 
       NR==1 {n=length(); for(i=1;i<=n;i++) printf "%-3s", i ; print ""}
             {$1=$1}1' file

1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89
-  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  V  R  E  V  -  C  -  S  E  Q  A  E  T  G  P  C  R  A  M  I  S  R  W  Y  F  D  V  T  E  G  K  C  A  P  F  F  Y  G  G  C  G  G  N  R  N  N  F  D  T  E  E  Y  C  M  A  V  C  G  -  -  -  -  -
-  -  P  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  R  R  K  L  -  C  -  I  L  H  R  N  P  G  R  C  Y  D  K  I  P  A  F  Y  Y  N  Q  K  K  K  Q  C  E  R  F  D  W  S  G  C  G  G  N  S  N  R  F  K  T  I  E  E  C  R  R  T  C  I  G  -  -  -  -
-  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  A  P  D  F  -  C  -  L  E  P  P  Y  D  G  P  C  R  A  L  H  L  R  Y  F  Y  N  A  K  A  G  L  C  Q  T  F  Y  Y  G  G  C  L  A  K  R  N  N  F  E  S  A  E  D  C  M  R  T  C  -  -  -  -  -  -
```

Comment: Just one question. What is the 1 for at the end of "}"?

Comment: `1` is shorthand for the default `print` operation in `awk`.

Comment: Very nice touch with the separation by 10 with `sed`...

Comment: @Caterina not to be confused with the `\1` in `sed` which is the first backreference that reinserts what was captured between the `(...)` in the find part of the `s/find/replace/` substitution form.